# Calling Cell Reference from Different Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to  multiply two variable of different workbook in another workbook and below code look like everything is fine but its not working... appreciated if someone solving the issue

```
'PTC is WB1 cell reference and Outstval is WB2 Cell reference  
wkb.Activate
With wkb.Worksheets(1)                   
    .Range("C4").Formula = "= ( " & PTC.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, xlExternal) & "*" & Outstval.Address(False, False, xlR1C1, xlExternal) & " ) "
     lr = .Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
     .Range("C4").Resize(lr - 1, 5).FillDown
     .Calculate                                                                 
End With
```

Comment: Can you specify what is not working ? are you getting an error, if so at what line ? or the end result is not what you expected ?

Comment: I think it's because of your second `Range`, instead of `Outstval.Address(False, False, xlR1C1, xlExternal)` use `Outstval.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, xlExternal)`

Comment: You're using `R1C1` notation. Try doing it with `A1` instead

Comment: @ShaiRado i got the error at 3rd line (doing Multiplication)...  if range c4 got the formula need to drag that upto last row and five columns

Comment: @Tom it works with both (tested). can you share the code section where you define and set your `PTC` and `Outstval` `Range`s ?

Comment: Are all three workbooks open when you run this code?

Comment: @Tom yes tom  `set  PTC = wb1.Sheets(2).Range("D12")` and in wb2 setting a range for Outstval  `Set Outstval = sera1.Offset(2, 0)`

Comment: and what is `sera1`? Also, as a sidenote using sheet variables like `Sheet(1)` is not very good practice as the sheet can easily be changed by a user switching the order of the sheets.

Comment: @Tom it show like this in `C4= ( [list.xlsm]Sheet2!R12C4*'[20170221_Par Mosec Marquez Waterfall (1T SLCE) - EIS.xlsb]Waterfall'!R[27]C[13] )` but not calculating.. its showing like string data

Comment: so you're saying your macro just returns `( [list.xlsm]Sheet2!R12C4*'[20170221_Par Mosec Marquez Waterfall (1T SLCE) - EIS.xlsb]Waterfall'!R[27]C[13] )` in the cell `C4`?

Comment: @Tom yes - but it not calculating anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155248/discussion-between-tom-and-ashok).